# How to autofocus redux field

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want to autofocus first redux field. I have tried many different options available but none of them worked. So whenever the form gets created, it should focus to first field.

```
           <Field
              name={'Email'}
              label="Email *"
              onFocusCb={this.hideDoneButton}
              component={FormInput}
              containerStyle={styles.inputStyle}
              clearButtonMode={'always'}
              autoCorrect={false}
          />
```

I have created the component{FormInput} outside the class. Below is the code for the same.

```
const FormInput = props =>
(<View style={props.containerStyle}>
<FormTextInput
    autoFocus={true}
    multiline
    style={props.style}
    autoCapitalize={props.autoCapitalize}
    clearButtonMode={props.clearButtonMode}
    selectionColor={props.selectionColor}
    value={props.input.value}
    onFocus={props.onFocusCb}
    keyboardType={props.keyboardType}
    label={props.label}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
    defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
    onChangeText={text => props.input.onChange(text)}
    onEndEditing={() => {
      if (props.onEndEditing) {
        props.onEndEditing();
      }
      if (props.input.onEndEditing) {
        props.input.onEndEditing();
      }
    }}
/>
</View>);
```

Comment: What approach did you try that didn't work? There might be some specific context in your app that makes the standard approaches ineffective. So please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Could I see the `FormInput`? Is it a custom component you have control over?

Comment: updated the question above

Comment: Thanks.  Ok, so what's `FormTextInput`? Is it a custom field that you can modify the code of, or is it from some library? (If so, which?)

Comment: For this to work, then somewhere down the line (maybe in FormTextInput), the property `autoFocus` must be placed on an actual regular `<input />` element.  So that's why I'm asking about it. If `FormTextInput` is part of a library then that library hopefully has some documentation on how you're supposed to pass down properties to the underlying input. If it's a component you (or your team) wrote yourself, then we could look at the code and see where the `autoFocus` property gets lost.

Comment: Yes its a custom component. Now the latest update is that its working on autoFocus={true} but its not staying autofocused. It only works as soon as the component gets rendered i.e for few milisec

Comment: Ok. Could that be because you use FormTextInput and/or FormInput  in several places in the same form, so that we now have multiple fields that all have the autoFocus property?

Comment: If so, you could switch back to having the autoFocus on the top level component (Field) and then in `FormInput` you return  `<FormTextInput
    autoFocus={props.autoFocus} ... etc.  ... />`

Comment: Yes there are multiple fields for the same FormInput but i tried setting autoFocus={true} only to my required field and setting the other fields to autoFocus={false}...but that also did not work.

Comment: I tried doing autoFocus={props.autoFocus} in top level comp and passing autoFocus={true} in required field..but its not staying focused, it quickly gets nonfocused

Comment: I see. Sounds tricky.. Can you see what the field is losing focus to? Like, if there's something else on the page that now has focus instead? If you temporarily comment out code so that only one field renders, then maybe you can see if it's losing focus because of interference from other inputs, or if it has something to do with how `FormTextInput` work. Otherwise I actually don't know what to try next. Sorry.

Comment: Yes tried commenting rest of fields and renders only 1 field, but still loses focus immediately..alright great thanks @jonahe

Comment: If you render just one field, but a very simplified one, does the field still lose focus then as well? For example, look at the very simplified component `Custom` in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/mofsh1wj/  If that works, then maybe it would be worth posting the code of  ` FormTextInput` as well, to see if there's something there that could explain the issue.   (All of this is of course optional. I understand if you don't want to go deeper down this rabbit hole.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTML5 attribute [`autoFocus`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp). This solution is not related to Redux form.

```js
<Field
          autoFocus
          name={'Email'}
          label="Email *"
          onFocusCb={this.hideDoneButton}
          component={FormInput}
          containerStyle={styles.inputStyle}
          clearButtonMode={'always'}
          autoCorrect={false}
      />
```

There are ways to do it within Redux-form, like setting the props `ref`, `withRef`, use [`getRenderedComponent()`](http://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/api/Field.md/#-code-getrenderedcomponent-code-) and then calling `.focus()`,  but for this simple behavior it's not clear what the benefit, over just using `autoFocus`, would be.

Comment: In html `autofocus` alone should work, but according to react native docs, you should use `autoFocus={true}` with react native. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Comment: Good find @HåkenLid . Using another persons JSFiddle as a base, this form seems to work with `autoFocus`. https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/mofsh1wj/

Comment: I tried setting autoFocus{true} but still its not working @HåkenLid

Comment: In redux-form autoFocus also does not work for me, any solutions?